# Testing with Jest returns TypeError stating my test function is not a function

Tags: testing, jestjs

I have a simple `capitalize` function that I'm trying to test. From the js/tests folder, I'm running `npm test` to run jest on the `capitalize.test.js` test file, but both my tests return the error  `TypeError: (0 , _capitalize.default) is not a function`. Also tried typing `npm test -- capitalize.test.js` in the console.

Here's my file tree, excluding my node modules for brevity:

```
├── README.md
├── js
│   ├── scripts
│   │   ├── analyzeArray.js
│   │   ├── caeserCipher.js
│   │   ├── calculator.js
│   │   ├── capitalize.js
│   │   └── reverseString.js
│   └── tests
│       └── capitalize.test.js
├── package-lock.json
└── package.json
```

#### package.json

```
  "name": "odin-jesttesting",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Jest testing for OdinJS",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "testing",
    "jest",
    "odin",
    "odinjs",
    "odin-jesttesting"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "jest": "^29.5.0"
  }
}
```

#### capitalize.js

```
const firstChar = str => Array.from(str)[0];
const capitalize = str => firstChar(str).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);

export { capitalize };
```

#### capitalize.test.js

```
import capitalize from '../scripts/capitalize';

it('should capitalize first letter', () => {
  expect(capitalize('foo')).toBe('Foo');
});

it('should capitalize first letter', () => {
  expect(capitalize('egg')).toBe('Egg');
});
```

#### Error in the console

```
  ● should capitalize first letter

 TypeError: (0 , _capitalize.default) is not a function

      2 |
      3 | it('should capitalize first letter', () => {
    > 4 |   expect(capitalize('foo')).toBe('Foo');
        |                    ^
      5 | });
      6 |
      7 | it('should capitalize first letter', () => {

      at Object.<anonymous> (js/tests/capitalize.test.js:4:20)
```

If I move to the js/scripts folder and run `npm capitalize.js` with a `console.log(capitalize('foo')` or `console.log(capitalize('egg')` the function works fine and returns `Foo` and `Egg` respectively, but the Jest tests fail. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting capitalize using named export syntax, and importing it using default import syntax. Replace `export {capitalize} with export default capitalize` OR replace `import capitalize from ...` with `import {capitalize} from ...`